# Can I control Windows 7 Task Scheduler conditions with Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have written a Backup server with AutoIT script, but when I schedule it in the Task Scheduler, it put it under the condition the if the computer is not plugged in to a power cord, it will not run the talk after logging in.  Does anyone know if Powershell script can change that condition without having to go straight to the Task Scheduler, if so, could you help me with the script since I have very little knowledge of Pwershell script

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog, http://www.vinithmenon.com/2012/11/powershell-v3-scheduled-job-to-start.html, it has steps on how to use scheduled tasks module in powershell, you would need to get powershell V3